# Dynamic Layout android

Tags: android, layout, android-gridlayout

I'm new to Android and it seems that I cannot find the right layout for my problem. 
I have a bunch of buttons (also added dynamically during the execution of the app) that I want to display in a column.

I have used a `LinearLayout` (Vertical) and it does the works pretty well in a tablet. The problem is that on smaller screen, like phones, there's not enough space to visualize all the buttons and half of them are not shown.

Is there a layout that allows me to do either something like "show all the button in a column, and then when there's no more space, start piling up in the next column", or something that allows it to resize the buttons in order to fit them all onto the one column?

I have tried with `GridLayout` but with no success (i.e. even setting the `android:columnCount=3` I didn't notice any change)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use a ListView?

Comment: I would have rather sow all of them, instead than a scrollable ListView, but indeed is a good alternative